# Как правильно добавить запись в базу данных Access?

Tags: c#, winforms, access

У меня есть база данных на Access имеется 2-е таблицы Пользователи и Личные_данные, я хотел что бы при создании новых записей в [Личные_данные] автоматически добавлялся код [Пользователи.ID] в поле  [Личные_данные].[Пользователь]

[image: Таблица Пользователи]

[image: Таблица Личные_данные]

А также они связанны по полям которые указаны на Рисунке 3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создаю запросы на добавление записей в Таблицу [Личные_данные]

```
 string Str_command = "INSERT INTO `Личные_данные` (`Фамилия`,`Имя`,`Отчество`," +
            "`Дата_рождения`,`Телефон`,`Пол`,`Семейное_положение`,`Образование`,`Занятость`,`Инвалидность`,`Место_работы`," +
            "`Район`,`Город`,`Населенный_пункт`,`Улица`,`Дом`,`Квартира`,`Местность`," +
            "`Полис_ОМС`,`Снилс`,`Документ`) VALUES (@LName,@FName,@Patr,@Date,@Phone,@Sex,@MtlSts," +
            "@Educ,@Epl,@Disab,@Work,@Area,@Sity,@HumStat,@Street,@Hom,@Flat,@Terr,@Polis,@Snils,@Doc)";


        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(Str_command, dc.getConnection());

        command.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LastName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@FName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Patr", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Patronymic;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateOfBirth;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Phone;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Sex", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Sex;
        command.Parameters.Add("@MtlSts", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = MaritalStats;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Educ", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Education;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Epl", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Employment;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Work", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PlaceOfWork;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Disab", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Disability;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Area", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Area;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Sity", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Sity;
        command.Parameters.Add("@HumStat", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = HumanStattlement;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Street", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Street;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Hom", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Home;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Flat", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Flat;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Terr", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Terrain;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Polis", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PolisOMS;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Snils", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = SNILS;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Doc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Document;


        dc.Connection();


        if (!CheckNullTxtBox())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не все значения введенны", "Введите значение!");
        }
        else
        {
                if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Данные успешно добавлены");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка данные не добавлены");
                }
            }
        }
        dc.Disconnection();
```

Так же создаю запрос на добавление в поле [Личные_данные].[Пользователь] из поля [Пользователи].[ID]

```
 string com = "INSERT INTO Личные_данные ( Пользователь ) SELECT [Пользователи].[ID] AS Выражение1 FROM Пользователи;";

        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(com, dc.getConnection());

        comm.Parameters.Add("Личные_данные.[Пользователь]", OleDbType.Integer);
```

> Запросы по отдельности отлично работают

Но когда пытаюсь воспроизвести все вместе вылезает ошибка "Вы не можете добавить или изменить запись, потому что связанная запись требуется в таблице "пользователи"."

Памогите пожалуйста

> Как мне кажется 1 запрос заполняет 1ую строчку, а 2ой уже 2ую поэтому такая ошибка, может выполнить 2 запроса как 1? только вот как не знаю

Comment: Автоматически ничего и никуда не добавляется. Сначала одним запросом создаёте пользователя, потом вторым записываете его параметры.

Comment: @Akina - это я прекрасно понимаю, дело в том что пользователь уже создан остается добавить пациентов с личными данными, что б вы понимали суть: У одного пользователя должны быть свои пациенты вот.

Comment: Хорошо. "Автоматически ничего и никуда не добавляется. Сначала одним запросом создаёте пациента, потом вторым записываете его личные данные." так понятнее?

Comment: @Akina - посмотрите на мой код повнимательнее, там у меня выполняться сначала 1 запрос на добавления кода, а 2ой как раз заполняет личные данные, может быть у меня в коде ошибка?

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас ошибка в структуре БД. По связи таблиц выходит так, что под одним и тем же логином и паролем может фигурировать несколько разных людей, т.к. у вас связь между таблицами `один-ко-многим`, а по здравой логике такого быть не должно, т.е. должна быть связь `один-к-одному` и поле `Логин` должно быть уникальным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внесение данных придется разбить на три этапа:

```
//Вносим данные в таблицу Личные_данные
result = await InsertPrivatePersonData(person);
//Получаем значение поля код только что сделанной записи в тб.Личные_данные
int id = await GetIdLastInsertedPrivatePersonData();
//Вносим данные в тб. Пользователи
result = await InsertLoginPersonData(person, id);
```

*Да, и похоже, что вложенные запросы и транзакции в `Access` или `OleDB` не поддерживаются. У меня почему-то это вызывало ошибки.*

Вот целиком класс работы с БД

```
public class AccessDataContext : IDataContext
{
    public AccessDataContext()
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Создание экземпляра соединения
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private OleDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=Data\\People.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";

        return new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение полного списка людей с их логинами
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<List<PersonViewModel>> LoadPeopleAsync()
    {
        List<PersonViewModel> result = new List<PersonViewModel>();

        try
        {
            using (var con = GetConnection())
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Личные_данные.Код, Личные_данные.Имя, Личные_данные.Фамилия, Личные_данные.Отчество, Пользователи.Логин, Пользователи.Пароль " +
                                  "FROM Личные_данные " +
                                  "INNER JOIN Пользователи " +
                                  "ON Личные_данные.Код = Пользователи.Личные_данные_Код;";
                con.Open();
                using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        var person = new PersonViewModel
                        {
                            Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            FirstName = reader.GetString(1),
                            LastName = reader.GetString(2),
                            MiddleName = reader.GetString(3),
                            Login = reader.GetString(4),
                            Password = reader.GetString(5),
                        };
                        //
                        result.Add(person);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Внесение записи о новом человеке
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<int> AddPersonAsync(PersonViewModel person)
    {
        int result = 0;

        try
        {
            //Вносим данные в таблицу Личные_данные
            result = await InsertPrivatePersonData(person);
            //Получаем значение поля код только что сделанной записи в тб.Личные_данные
            int id = await GetIdLastInsertedPrivatePersonData();
            //Вносим данные в тб. Пользователи
            result = await InsertLoginPersonData(person, id);
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление записи в тб. Пользователи
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<int> InsertLoginPersonData(PersonViewModel person, int id)
    {
        int result = 0;
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Пользователи (Личные_данные_Код, Логин, Пароль) " +
                                  "VALUES (@Id, @Login, @Passwd);";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Id",
                OleDbType.Integer)
            { Value = id });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Login",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.Login });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Passwd",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.Password });

            con.Open();
            result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение Id последней записи в тб. Личные_данные
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<int> GetIdLastInsertedPrivatePersonData()
    {
        int id = 0;

        using (var con = GetConnection())
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1  Личные_данные.Код FROM Личные_данные " +
                              "ORDER BY Личные_данные.Код DESC";
            con.Open();
            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                }
            }
        }

        return id;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление записи в тб. Личные_данные
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<int> InsertPrivatePersonData(PersonViewModel person)
    {
        int result = 0;

        using (var con = GetConnection())
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Личные_данные (Имя, Фамилия, Отчество) " +
                              "VALUES (@FName, @LName, @MName);";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FName",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.FirstName });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@LName",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.LastName });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@MName",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.MiddleName });

            con.Open();
            result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Удаление человека
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<int> RemovePersonAsync(PersonViewModel person)
    {
        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var con = GetConnection())
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Личные_данные WHERE Личные_данные.Код = @Id";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Id",
                OleDbType.Integer)
                { Value = person.Id });

                con.Open();
                result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }

        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Изменение записи о пользователе
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<int> UpdatePersonAsync(PersonViewModel person)
    {
        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            //обновляем в тб. Личные_данные
            result = await UpdatePrivatePersonData(person);
            //обновляем в тб. Пользователи
            result = await UpdateLoginPersonData(person);
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обновление записи в тб. Личные_данные
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<int> UpdatePrivatePersonData(PersonViewModel person)
    {
        int result = 0;
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Личные_данные" +
                " SET Имя = @FName, Фамилия = @LName, Отчество = @MName" +
                " WHERE Личные_данные.Код = @Id";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FName",
            OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.FirstName });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@LName",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.LastName });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@MName",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.MiddleName });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Id",
            OleDbType.Integer)
            { Value = person.Id });

            con.Open();
            result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обновление записи в тб. Пользователи
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<int> UpdateLoginPersonData(PersonViewModel person)
    {
        int result = 0;
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Пользователи" +
                " SET Логин = @Login, Пароль = @Passwd" +
                " WHERE Пользователи.Личные_данные_Код = @Id";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Login",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.Login });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Passwd",
                OleDbType.VarWChar)
            { Value = person.Password });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Id",
            OleDbType.Integer)
            { Value = person.Id });

            con.Open();
            result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Вот такой пример

[image: работа примера программы]

лежит [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WindowsFormsAccessDB).

Comment: ценю вашу работу, заберу пригодиться, но мне нужно именно смотрите что: программа представляет из себя "Электронную мед карту" и я хотел что бы врач который пользуется этой программой мог зайти под своей учетной записью и добавлять пациентов,что то в этом роде, но после ваше комментария я начал сомневаться в своих мыслях и в том что я делаю

Comment: да я еще хотел сказать, ваш код хорош, но понять мне его пока рановато, я пытаюсь делась все очень просто, могу скинуть проект на GH

Comment: кидайте, если хотите, могут чего-нибудь подсказать...

Comment: извеняюсь были проблемы с созданием репозитория, все таки 1ый раз [ https://github.com/SmurW/Medical_record ]