# Создается тест . Первая форма имя это тестируемый человек. А вторая форма тест. Имя и оценка появляются на разных строчках

Tags: c#, access

Имя

```
public partial class Form202 : Form
{
    public string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Анкета.accdb";

    public Form202()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFile();
    }

    void SaveFile()
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) //connString - строка подключения
        {
            string commText = "insert into Данные (Имя) values (@imya)";
            OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(commText, conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imya", textBox1.Text); //добавляем первый параметр со значением из textBox1.Text
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Добавить не удалось!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Оценки

```
public partial class Form203 : Form
{
    public string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Анкета.accdb";

    public Form203()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Данные (Оценки) VALUES (@eval)";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eval", label10.Text); // Поле "Оценки" в таблице типа символьное, иначе требуется преобразование типа
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `INSERT INTO Данные (Оценки) VALUES (@eval)` эта оценка для кого предназначена?

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы про нормализацию не слышали, и как обновлять данные (а не просто вставлять) не знаете?

Comment: @tym32167 не знаю

Comment: [SQL UPDATE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: @tym32167  string commText = "UPDATE Данные (Имя) values (@imya)";????

Comment: Такой update поменяет имя у всех записей в таблице. Вам надо использовать where с указанием кода нужного человека. И также с оценкой. Находите нужного чела по имени, определяете его код, а затем делаете update со значением оценки с where.

Comment: @Bulson напишите пожалуйста код

Comment: Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542) или вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1076493/222542)